# How can I use the Apple Push Notification Service (apns) with php?

Tags: php, ssl, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to connect to Apples Push Notification Service (apns) with php. If I use the  command

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.push.apple.com:2195 -cert AppCert.pem -key AppKeyNoPass.pem -CAfile ca.pem
```

on the console I get a long message with "Verify return code: 0 (ok)" in the last line. If I use the following PHP code I get some warnings.

```
$uuid = '11111111-22222222-33333333-44444444-55555555-66666666-77777777-88888888';
$url = 'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195';

$streamContext = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'App.pem');
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'cafile', 'ca.pem');

$socketClient = stream_socket_client($url, $error, $errorString, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);
```

Here are the PHP Warnings for stream_socket_client()

```
Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14094416:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert certificate unknown
Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: Failed to enable crypto
Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error)
```

Do you have any idea? Do I have some problems with the certificate formats?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I used [this Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12) and everything worked fine for me. There is everything in detail about the key files and also a [php push example file](http://d1xzuxjlafny7l.cloudfront.net/downloads/SimplePush.zip) for download. Hope that helps.

Comment: yeap, that's the best tutorial there is